# Null Object Pattern in a self-referencing type

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Suppose I have a class named `Node`, which represents a node in a hierarchical structure.
For instance it could look something like this:

```csharp
public class Node
{
  public readonly string Data { get; set; }
  public readonly Node Parent { get; set; }
  public readonly List<Node> Children { get; } = new()

  public Nome(string Data, Node parent)
  {
    Data = data;
    Parent = parent;
  }
}
```

Notice the property `Parent` is of type `Node` and it's non-nullable, so I cannot assign `null` to it.
Now suppose I want to implement the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) for this class, for instance  to create the root node.

I found myself in a chicken and egg situation because I cannot create a `Node` without having a node.

Are there any alternatives except making `Parent` nullable?

Comment: Personally I consider the "null object pattern" as an _anti-pattern_ for reasons too numerous to list. Instead, I recommend using a custom union type.

Comment: Actually, **why not** mark the `Parent` property as `Node? Parent`? (i.e. mark it as nullable). After all, it _can_ be validly `null` when the node is the root - and add a brief comment: "this property is `null` when the `Node` is the root of the graph").

Comment: Also, the question-title says "self-referencing object", but I'm not actually seeing any self-referential code here... Please clarify.

Comment: @Dai you are correct and I appreciate your feedback. I changed the question title and hopefully it's clearer.

Comment: Now it says "self-referencing object" - but there's still zero self-referencing going on in your code.

Comment: I changed to "Null Object Pattern in a self-referencing TYPE". Do you see any problem with that?

Comment: ...hang on... what do you mean by "self-referencing", exactly? Just because `class Node` has a member of type `Node` doesn't mean it's "self-referencing", that's not what that term means (at least in my experience). For example, just because `class String` has a `String ToString()` member doesn't mean the `String` type is "self-referencing".

Comment: First of all, English isn't my first language, so I assume I may be wrong. I used the term "self-referencing type" because the type `Node` keeps a reference (in this case multiple references) to an instance of the same type `Node`. It's not the same as your `String` example. I searched the Web to look for usages of this term and found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RSUUbZhxxU). I'm not saying I'm correct, but the video (I think) uses the term in a similar way. Thanks for your interactions.

Answer (score 1):

If you only use one class you need nulltype but you can use an interface for the start:

```cs
    public class Node : NodeRoot {
        public string Data { get; init; }
        public Node? Parent { get; init; }
        public List<Node> Children { get; init; } = new();

        private Node(string data) {
            Data = data;
        }

        private Node(string data, Node parent) {
            Data = data;
            Parent = parent;
        }

        public static Node Factory(string data, Node parent) => new(data, parent);

        public static INodeRoot Factory(string data) => new Node(data);
    }

    public interface INodeRoot {
        public string Data { get; }
        public List<Node> Children { get; }
    }
```

Comment: In .NET, interface names should start with an `I` - and adjectives should precede nouns, so it should be named `public interface IRootNode`.

Comment: The OP's `Node` type is intended to be mutable, so the property setters should be `set`, not `init`.

Comment: Why are there static factory methods? They don't add any value, so just expose the two constructors.

Answer (score -1):

You could keep the field non nullable but force null into it by using the syntax `= null!` (note the `!` which tells the compiler to trust you).
I would probably combine this technique with a subclass and/or static instance to be used as the root parent, and prevent issues when accessing that null parent field (or add a computed field `isRoot`).

Comment: Using `= null!` still violates the implied contract, and the principle of least astonishment. If a C# 8.0+ class property with a reference-type has  the `[NotNull]` attribute (it's added by the compiler) then as a consumer _I'm going to trust it_, what you're proposing goes against that.

Comment: Which is why I suggest to hide that in a dedicated subclass, which would protect users of that class, thus respecting the contract (from a public perspective).

Comment: Yes, but that's an alternative suggestion. I'm saying your initial suggestion is a _bad_ suggestion (but subclassing is fine).